# ASP.NET Web Api 2 - Log every incoming request for specific actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am working with ASP.NET Web Api 2. I have written two `Filter Attributes` which check every incoming request for specific headers and if the header keys are not present they return Unauthorized response to users.

This is what I am doing (one of the filters):

```
public class HeaderFilterAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var req = actionContext.Request;


            if (! req.Headers.Contains("api-key") || req.Headers.GetValues("api-key") == null)
            {
                actionContext.Response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                actionContext.Response.Content = new StringContent("Token required", Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
            }
        }
}
```

Now If the request contains valid header keys and they have reached the correct action method or endpoint, I want to log certain details about the request.

**What is the right way to create a filter attribute for this scenario? Which method this filter attribute will override? Or can I achieve the desired result without creating a filter attribute.**   I think it will not make sense to override `OnAuthorization()`

Answer (score 1):

Make a new filter extending `ActionFilterAttribute`. Your authorization filters will always run first then the logging filter logs your accepted requests.

```
public class MyLogFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // log info

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Add to a base controller class to log all actions.

```
[HeaderFilter]
[MyLogFilter]
public abstract class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
}

public class MyApiController : BaseApiController
{
}
```

Comment: How to pass dependency in MyLogFilter e.g. logger instance?

Comment: @HimalayaGarg that's out-of-scope for this question. But it would depend on your logger and DI framework. I'm sure it's been answered on SO before.